# Why is this switch statement not recognizing subString?

Tags: java, switch-statement, substring

I am creating a class `Course` which represents a Course object with three attributes, `courseID`, `letterGrade`, and `numberGrade`.

`numberGrade` is calculated from `letterGrade` using the `computeGrade()` method. I'm currently testing my `Course` class and finding that the switch statement used in `computeGrade` does not recognize the relevant `substring`.

Why is this happening?

```
public void computeGrade() {
    switch (letterGrade.substring(0,1)) {
        case "A": numberGrade = 4.0;
        case "B": numberGrade = 3.0;
        case "C": numberGrade = 2.0;
        case "D": numberGrade = 1.0;
        case "F": numberGrade = 0.0;
        default: numberGrade = 999;
    }
    if(letterGrade.endsWith("+") && !letterGrade.startsWith("A") && !letterGrade.startsWith("F")) {
        numberGrade += 0.3;
    }
    else if(letterGrade.endsWith("-") && !letterGrade.startsWith("D") && !letterGrade.startsWith("F")) {
        numberGrade -= 0.3;
    }
}
```

My tester loops through an array of possible grades

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] grades = {"A", "A-", "B+", "B", "B-", "C+", "C", "C-", "D+", "D", "F"};
    Course course = new Course("COP2253", " ");
    String toString;
    for (int i = 0; i < grades.length; i++) {
        course.updateGrade(grades[i]);
        toString = course.toString();
        System.out.println(toString + "\n");

    }
```

with the following output

```
COP2253     A   999.0
COP2253     A-  998.7
COP2253     B+  999.3
COP2253     B   999.0
COP2253     B-  998.7
COP2253     C+  999.3
COP2253     C   999.0
COP2253     C-  998.7
COP2253     D+  999.3
COP2253     D   999.0
COP2253     F   999.0
```

P.S. I'm fairly sure the constructor,

```
public Course(String courseID, String letterGrade) {
    this.courseID = courseID;
    this.letterGrade = letterGrade;
    computeGrade();
}
```

`updateGrade()`,

```
public void updateGrade(String grade) {
    letterGrade = grade;
    computeGrade();
}
```

and `toString()`

```
public String toString() {
    String grade = courseID + "\t\t" + letterGrade + "\t" + numberGrade;
    return grade;
}
```

aren't an issue.

Comment: You forgot to add `break;` statements after each case in your switch. So whatever the `letterGrade.substring` returns, you'll always go to the default case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should add `break;` after each *case*. Without it, your program crawls to the `default`, no matter what's in the `switch`.

Read the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html) to better understand *switch-case* statmenets:

> All statements after the matching case label are executed in sequence,
>   regardless of the expression of subsequent case labels, **until a break
>   statement is encountered**.

Comment: That's not entirely correct; although traditionally the `switch` executes until a break is found, you can throw exceptions in any branch and that will stop execution of the `switch`.

Comment: Yes, this is true.  In this context, that won't happen at all.

Comment: A return statement in a `break` also terminates execution.

Answer (score 3):

Without using `break;` after each case-statement, switch will use the next case until the default. So everytime you use this switch-statement it will run until `default`

Answer (score 2):

What you currently have is a [fall through](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html) case - since there is no `break` encountered, your code will always execute every branch, and the last result will be what is used.

You **must** add `break` to the end of your `switch` statements in this context.